# Xml Deserialization - Element with attributes and a value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm not quite sure how to deserialize the following:

```
<property>
    <price display="yes" plusSAV="no" tax="yes">1000000</price>
    ...
</property>
```

In my C# model, I have a Property object, which contains a Price property, declared as follows:

```
    [XmlElement("price")]
    public Price Price { get; set; }
```

Then in the Price class, I have the following:

```
   [Serializable]
    public class Price : BaseDisplayAttribute, IDataModel
    {        
        [XmlElement("price")]
        public string PriceValueString { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("plusSAV")]
        public string PlusSAVString { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("tax")]
        public string TaxString { get; set; }

        ....
    }
```

All the attributes are deserializing correctly, but the price element is not.  Have I declared it correctly here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [XmlText Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
[XmlText]
public string PriceValueString { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yup, that's it.  I actually just figured it out and came back to post the answer, but looks like you beat me to it.  Thanks Selman :)

Comment: glad if I could help :)